# Insert the table data based on grouping of two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have a oracle table with the following format, 
For eg:

```
JLID    Dcode   SID     TDT            QTY  
8295783 3119255 9842    3/5/2018        14  
8269771 3119255 9842    3/6/2018        11  
8302211 3119255 1126    3/1/2018        19
```

Here I have different SID for the same Dcode, now I need to get the SID with the maximum Qty. (i.e) for SID 9842 - (14+11)=25, for SID 1126 it is 19, then the results should be on SID 9842. So, our query should returns the following results

```
JLID    Dcode   START_DT    END_DT           SID       
111    3119255  3/1/2018    3/31/2018 12:00  9842
```

Startdate and enddate should be calculated from TDT (i.e) start date is the first date of the month and the end date is the last date of the month
Can anyone please suggest me some ideas to do it.

Comment: may with analytic functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be as simple as this:

```
SELECT Dcode, start_date, end_date, SID FROM (
    SELECT Dcode, SID, TRUNC(start_date, 'MONTH') AS start_date
         , LAST_DAY(end_date) AS end_date
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Dcode ORDER BY total_qty DESC ) AS rn
      FROM (
        SELECT Dcode, SID, MIN(TDT) AS start_date, MAX(TDT) AS end_date
             , SUM(QTY) AS total_qty
          FROM mytable
         GROUP BY Dcode, SID
    )
) WHERE rn = 1
```

In the inner most subquery I aggregation to get the range of dates and total quantity for particular values of `Dcode` and `SID`. Then I use an anaylitic (window) function to get the row for which total quantity is the greatest. (You would want to use `RANK()` in place of `ROW_NUMBER()` in the event you want to return more than one value of SID with the same quantity.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option which doesn't contain JLID = 111 in the final result as I have no idea where you took it from.

```
SQL> with test (jlid, dcode, sid, tdt, qty) as
  2        (select 8295783, 3119255, 9842, date '2018-03-05', 14 from dual union
  3         select 8269771, 3119255, 9842, date '2018-08-22', 11 from dual union
  4         select 8302211, 3119255, 1126, date '2018-03-01', 19 from dual union
  5         --
  6         select 1234567, 1112223, 1000, date '2018-06-16', 88 from dual
  7        )
  8    select dcode,
  9           min (trunc (tdt, 'mm')) start_dt,      --> MIN
 10           max (last_day (tdt)) end_dt,           --> MAX
 11           sid
 12      from (select dcode,
 13                   sid,
 14                   tdt,
 15                   sqty,
 16                   rank () over (partition by dcode order by sqty desc) rnk
 17              from (select dcode,
 18                           sid,
 19                           tdt,
 20                           sum (qty) over (partition by dcode, sid) sqty
 21                      from test))
 22     where rnk = 1
 23  group by dcode, sid;                                   --> GROUP BY

     DCODE START_DT         END_DT                  SID
---------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------
   1112223 01.06.2018 00:00 30.06.2018 00:00       1000
   3119255 01.03.2018 00:00 31.08.2018 00:00       9842

SQL>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but one thing is that whenever the month changes, it gives the duplicate records, For eg: 0000155 01-JAN-13 31-JAN-13 7842
0000155 01-FEB-13 28-FEB-13 7842
0000155 01-MAR-13 31-MAR-13 7842
0000155 01-APR-13 30-APR-13 7842
0000155 01-MAY-13 31-MAY-13 7842
0000155 01-JUN-13 30-JUN-13 7842
0000155 01-JUL-13 31-JUL-13 7842
0000155 01-AUG-13 31-AUG-13 7842
0000155 01-JUN-14 30-JUN-14 7842
0000155 01-JUL-14 31-JUL-14 7842
0000155 01-AUG-14 31-AUG-14 7842
0000155 01-SEP-14 30-SEP-14 7842, it should be 0000155 01-FEB-13 30-SEP-14 7842

Comment: I edited my message; you should apply MIN and MAX functions to DATE values and - consequentially - GROUP BY the rest of columns. Have a look.

Comment: I don't think you need the `DISTINCT` if you're using `GROUP BY`

Comment: Ah! Obviously, thank you, @David. During copy/paste session, I applied aggregation & "forgot" (right, didn't even notice it) to remove DISTINCT.

Comment: Also - the OP might not be completely clear - but you may want to partition by `Dcode` and `SID` in your innermost subquery.